# Python, compare two numpy arrays, find groups and remove duplicates

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays:

```
a = np.array([1,2,2,3,4,1,2,4,3,3])
b = np.array([100,200,200,100,400,100,200,400,100,100])
```

As you can see, there are two `1`'s in `a` and in the exact same indices, we can see two `100`'s in `b`. You can see three `3's` in `a` and in the exact same indices, we can again see three `100`'s.
This can also be seen for the other numbers, i.e. `2` and `4`.

I would like to compare these two arrays, get the groups, i.e. match `1` from `a` with the corresponding indices in `b`, and so on for the other numbers. Then I would like to eliminate **all but first** of each group in `b`, i.e.

```
result = np.array([100,200,100,400])
```

If the array `b` had unique group values (i.e. not repeating 100's for values `1` and `3` from array `a`), the problem would have been simply solved using `np.unique`. **But since, two numbers from array `a` have the same group number in array `b`, I am finding it difficult.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the indices of the unique values in `a` and use these to get the corresponding values from `b`:

```
indices = np.unique(a, return_index=True)[1]
b[indices]
```

Result:

```
array([100, 200, 100, 400])
```